# What is meant by "risks that neither outcome will turn out as planned"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Source:  http://www.economist.com/news/finance-and-economics/21652362-when-political-leaders-turn-option-writers-economics-bluffing

Please tell me what is meant by the under-lined part below

When push comes to shove, Greece will do a deal and Mr Cameron will persuade British voters to stay in the EU in his planned referendum. ***But there are risks that neither outcome will turn out as planned***. In both cases, political leaders are making a risky bet.

I don't understand what that means. Please help me understand it.

Thank you.

Comment: Mark such questions with 'sentence-meaning' and not grammar tag.

Comment: Which part is difficult for you to understand? "Neither", "outcome", "risks", "as planned"? What does your research show? Be specific when you ask a question and try to include your own research.

Comment: Sure Maulik Bhai, I will keep that in mind while posting in future. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here, it's short for **neither one of the outcomes**, which can also be translated to **neither this first outcome, nor that second one**.

See: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/grammaire/grammaire-britannique/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either, the first two examples are exactly similar to yours:

> **Neither** parent came to meet the teacher. (The mother didn’t come and the father didn’t come.)
>
> **Neither** dress fitted her. (There were two dresses and not one of them fitted her.)

Comment: No. I want to know what risks the article is talking about. Does it say that there are unspecified risks that will ensure that neither outcome will turn out as planned? Or does it say the fact of neither outcome turning out as planned itself is the risk? I am confused. Please help me.

Comment: @Policewala That's why you need to be specific when asking a question.

Comment: I agree Rahony. I promise to be more vigilant next time.

Comment: @Policewala It is better to edit your question now so that other users won't waste their time.

Comment: @Policewala: first one. It says that the outcomes **might not** turn out as planned.

Comment: @MadWard And they might not turn out as planned because of some unspecified risks? Am I right? IS the article wanting to say that?

Comment: @Policewala: that's it, but you shouldn't focus too much on the risks. Saying **there's a risk it might not go well** is the same as saying **there's a possibility that it might not go well**. You shouldn't take the *risks* here so literally.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the meaning of this phrase, it is useful to review the first paragraphs of your source article.

The author is discussing two current events. At the time, Britain was considering leaving the European Union, and Greece was considering defaulting on debts.  Either of these events would hurt the European Union.  In order to avoid this, the rest of the European Union was expected to negotiate with Britain and Greece to find a compromise.

The author says many people believe these are empty threats in order to gain a more favorable compromise.  These people expect a compromise to be reached, and afterwards the EU will proceed with business as usual.

The author suggests that the outcome is not as certain as those people expect it to be.  If the politicians who are making these threats make a mistake, their citizens may demand they carry out the threat.  The author is trying to convince us that these are not necessarily empty threats, and there is a real risk of disaster.

Now that we understand what the author is trying to say, we can make the sentence more clear:

```
But [despite the expectation of a compromise] there are risks.

There is a risk that Britain may not choose to stay in the EU as planned.

There is a risk that Greece may not make a deal as planned.

There are risks that neither outcome will turn out as planned.
```